# C#: Get values from libnotify c struct

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, libnotify

I am trying to access the c libnotify from my c# code to use libnotify on my linux laptop with dotnet core. 
But everytime there is a problem to get the values from the lib.

This is the problematic c code:

```
typedef struct _NotifyNotification NotifyNotification;
typedef struct _NotifyNotificationPrivate NotifyNotificationPrivate;

struct _NotifyNotification
{
    /*< private >*/
    GObject                    parent_object;

    NotifyNotificationPrivate *priv;
};

struct _NotifyNotificationPrivate
{
    guint32         id;
    char           *app_name;
    char           *summary;
    char           *body;

    /* NULL to use icon data. Anything else to have server lookup icon */
    char           *icon_name;

    /*
     * -1   = use server default
     *  0   = never timeout
     *  > 0 = Number of milliseconds before we timeout
     */
    gint            timeout;

    GSList         *actions;
    GHashTable     *action_map;
    GHashTable     *hints;

    gboolean        has_nondefault_actions;
    gboolean        updates_pending;

    gulong          proxy_signal_handler;

    gint            closed_reason;
};

NotifyNotification *
notify_notification_new (const char *summary,
                     const char *body,
                     const char *icon);
```

Now I created two structs in my c# code and an extern method:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    internal struct NotifyNotification
    {
        [FieldOffset(1)]
        public NotifyNotificationPrivate priv;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    internal struct NotifyNotificationPrivate
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public uint id;

        [FieldOffset(1)]
        public IntPtr app_name;

        [FieldOffset(2)]
        public IntPtr summary;

        [FieldOffset(5)]
        public int timeout;
    }

    [DllImport("libnotify.so.4", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    internal static extern IntPtr notify_notification_new([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string summary,
                                                          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string body,
                                                          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string icon);
```

With this code I cast everything to the structs:

```
NotifyNotification no = (NotifyNotification) Marshal.PtrToStructure(not, typeof(NotifyNotification));
Console.WriteLine(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(no.priv.summary));
```

The basics are working and I can call other functions from the libnotify with the pointer from the *notify_notification_new*-method.
But in the last line, with the WriteLine, the debugger says:

```
The program '...dll' has exited with code 0 (0x00000000).
```

There is no exception and no error. Whats going wrong? It is a problem with dotnet core? Because it is still in beta?

How can I get the text from the properties *app_name, summary, body*??

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]` says "dear compiler, I know what I'm doing, just... deal with it".  Unfortunately, you didn't know what you were doing.  `[FieldOffset]` takes the offset in bytes, not members.

```
struct _NotifyNotification
{
    /*< private >*/
    GObject                    parent_object;

    NotifyNotificationPrivate *priv;
};
```

GObject, presumably, is a pointer type.  That means it takes up either 4 bytes (x86) or 8 bytes (amd64). Since .NET Core for Linux is currently only supported on amd64, it's 8 bytes.  (Unless it's some other primitive structure).

`[FieldOffset(1)]` says "start reading 1 byte after the pointer".

Your next problem comes in that in C the struct is declared to have two members, the second one being a pointer.  Your C# struct says the second member is itself a struct.

So if the memory at the address pointed to by `notify_notification_new` looked like

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
```

You read

```
id = [01 02 03 04] => 0x04030201 (because Little-Endian)
app_name = [02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09] => 0x0908070605040302
summary = [03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A] => 0x0A09080706050403
timeout = [06 07 08 09] => 0x09080706
```

Much better would be to use Sequential layout:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct NotifyNotification
{
    private IntPtr parent_object;
    public IntPtr priv;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct NotifyNotificationPrivate
{
    public uint id;
    public IntPtr app_name;
    public IntPtr summary;
    private IntPtr body;
    private IntPtr icon_name;
    public int timeout;
    // If you're only ever reading one of these structures
    // you can skip the rest.  If you ever allocate one, be sure to
    // include all of the fields so the right amount of memory is created
}
```

Then:

```
NotifyNotification no = (NotifyNotification) Marshal.PtrToStructure(not, typeof(NotifyNotification));
NotifyNotificationPrivate noPriv = (NotifyNotificationPrivate) Marshal.PtrToStructure(no.priv, typeof(NotifyNotificationPrivate));
Console.WriteLine(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(noPriv.summary));
```

---

**Edit:** Though, the most predictable approach is to make a C library (or C++ with `extern "C"` declarations) which avoids copying/interpreting the structures altogether (it lets the C compiler take care of that):

```
extern "C" char* ReadNotificationSummary(NotifyNotification* notification)
{
    if (notification == nullptr || notification.priv == nullptr)
        return nullptr;

    return notification.priv->summary;
}
```

The matching C# declaration on that would be to have the function declared as returning `IntPtr` and to pass that still to `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi`; because if you declare it as returning a `string` the GC will think it's supposed to clean up the memory when the string goes out of scope.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer. That make sense. But:
After marshalling my not-pointer to the NotifyNotification-struct the value of priv is: _0x0000000000000001_.
So I cannot marshal it to the NotifyNotificationPrivate-struct. Why? That should be an other value, shoudn't it?

Comment: @bittnerd Ah, because GObject is a structure, not a pointer.  https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/master/gobject/gobject.h#L245-L252.  Your best bet is to make a small C library which you can pass a `NotifyNotification*` in and get a `NotifyNotificationPrivate*` out.  That way the C compiler can do field offset calculations, and you don't need to try to work around GObject's structure changing across versions of the GNOME framework.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
Actually I did not want to do it that way with an extra library. But I think this is the best way and I don't know an other way to get these values.

If you add that comment to your answer, I will accept it. :)

Comment: @bittnerd Done.  Shimming (everything) is the approach that's done in CoreFx on Linux, struct layouts having been the original motivating factor.  (Particularly with libraries that let fields be conditionally compiled-out)